# Tracking dependencies between systems

Tags: architecture, dependencies

I want to ask about your experience, with the tools which can be used to track 
dependencies between systems. During recent go live of a new version of application it has 
turned out that some processes running in other departments has been broken by change we introduced.

Did you tested any software which can be used to gather information regarding connections
between systems and their type ( SQL dependency, web-service dependency )?

The Enterprise Architect whould be an option, but maybe there is web-based solution?

Thanks,
Mariusz

Answer (score 0):

I use Enterprise Architect, it works well, but you need good routines to keep the information up to date. It can also be a lot of work to keep all the information at the level of detail that makes it usefull.

Another approach is to do all integration via a Service Bus. Then you can get a report from your ESB with a list of all connections to system X.